# How to connect boxplot's medians with multiple dataset

Tags: r, boxplot, median

I searched and didn't find my solution yet.  I'd like to have multiple lines to joint all boxplot's medians.  I saw a lot of example, but it only worked for one set of data (for example: https://digibio.blogspot.com/2016/09/box-plots-and-connect-by-median.html).  I want the graph looks as the image below, but if I use this command "stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", aes(group=1)".  It only plots one line.  I don't know how to plot for multiple lines.  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You probably want `aes(group = type)` not `aes(group = 1)` but it's difficult to know without seeing some example data.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @neilfws, Thanks neilfws, it plotted multiple lines when I used aes(group = type).  However, all the lines had the same black color.  I tried to use  "stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", aes(group=type), color=type)", I got an error "object 'type' not found".  It is really strange, because "type" is used to plot the lines.

Comment: @PeterRowan you need to put color inside `aes()` too; `aes(group = type, color = type)`.

Comment: @neilfws, Thank you.  It works as expected.